# Does Excel auto-refresh run when the excel workbook is closed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365, refresh

I am currently connecting to a SQL database from Excel and am trying to refresh that data at set intervals and to do so am using the auto refresh option located under connection properties. The documentation for that service ([here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/refresh-connected-imported-data-e76a38b0-e2e1-400b-9f2f-c87b9b18c092)) provides no information as to whether this refresh only occurs when the excel workbook is open or whether it will also run even if I have the file closed on my computer.

I am using the version of Excel that is part of the current Office 365 package which is 16.0.

Does anyone know the answer to that?

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh an external data range automatically when you open the workbook. Please review in [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/refresh-an-external-data-connection-in-excel-1524175f-777a-48fc-8fc7-c8514b984440). 
[image]

As for whether Excel auto-refresh run when the workbook is closed, I think it doesn't matter. Because it will be refreshed when opening.  Even if regular intervals are set, I guess it should not be refreshed when it is closed.

Comment: Nice answer,, ☺

Comment: I was hoping for an option for an auto refresh without having to open the workbook, but thanks! I ended up finding some workarounds.

Comment: If this reply is useful, could you mark it an answer?

Comment: Use case for a refresh when the file is *not* opened: file is on a SharePoint site and elements are placed on a page in that site. The refresh controls in SharePoint seem to only reload data from the file, but not make the file refresh its own external data. (Though this might be fixed in more recent versions of SharePoint, my experience with this is with Excel 2016 (non-365) and SP2013).